# Create DataSource using Administrator API

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I want to create a datasource using the ColdFusion Administrator API. All my credential are correct, that's for sure. I have followed this [tutorial](http://swalsh.org/blog/2013/03/20/programmatically-creating-new-datasource-in-coldfusion/) and also the Adobe [Tutorial](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf364104-7fcf.html#WS22A46B0F-C945-444a-8775-BF305446EF86). I don't know what am doing wrong in here.

```
<cfset adminAPI = createObject( 'component', 'cfide.adminapi.administrator' ) />
<cfset adminAPI.login( 'CFAdminPass', 'admin' ) />
<cfscript>
    dsnAPI = createObject( 'component', 'cfide.adminapi.datasource' );
    dsn = {
        driver = 'mysql5',
        name = 'cfdb',
        host = 'localhost',
        port = '3306',
        database = 'cfdb',
        username = 'root',
        password = 'mysqlpass'
    };
    // Finally, we save the new datasource
    dsnAPI.setMySQL5( argumentCollection = dsn );
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Admin API will not fully work If you have deployed Coldfusion in J2EE. I tested the code in CF11 and your code worked and successfully created the db.